# Debian 7, fstab, mount.cifs Invalid argument

Tags: linux, debian, mount, cifs

I try to mount cifs, but i have got following error and i don't find the error.

```
~# mount -a
~# mount error(22): Invalid argument
```

I try if in my /etc/fstab

```
//192.168.0.1/ShareRep /home/user/share cifs credentials=/usr/local/etc/whisper.credentials,uid=501,sec=ntml     0       0
```

my credentials file /usr/local/etc/whisper.credentials

```
username=user
password=password
```

I am on Debian 7.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of a more detailed error from `dmesg` I do see one typo that will cause things to fail. You have the option `sec=ntml` . This is is wrong and should be `sec=ntlm` . Notice how **ml** should be **lm**

It was determined that the OP was using **OS/X** as a **Samba** file server. There are some modifications (voodoo magic) to the options that need to be made to get this to work on most flavours of Linux. In partiuclar you need to specify the options `nounix,sec=ntlmssp,noperm`. I found this buried in a Ubuntu [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63046/how-to-mount-mac-os-x-lion-fileshare) (and answers) that mentions a thread of messages on the Apple forums. In summary this appeared:

> With reference to this post in Apple discussion community, you can try to mount with additional two options: nounix,sec=ntlmssp

A followup post suggested `noperm` might be needed as well.

If you modify your fstab entry to be this it may work:

```
//192.168.0.1/ShareRep /home/user/share cifs credentials=/usr/local/etc/whisper.credentials,uid=501,nounix,sec=ntlmssp,noperm     0       0
```

Comment: I have run dmesg after having modified the option sec=ntlm                        `[ 6949.362333] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22`
`[ 7579.194571] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22`
`[ 7754.364913] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22`

Comment: mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.0.1,unc=\\192.168.0.1\ShareRep,sec=ntlm,uid=501,user=requarts,pass=********
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Comment: with ntlmv2, `mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.0.1,unc=\\192.168.0.1\ShareRep,sec=ntlmv2,user=requarts,pass=********`
`mount error(22): Invalid argument`
`Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`

Comment: with ntlmssp, `mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.0.1,unc=\\192.168.0.1\ShareRep,sec=ntlmssp,user=requarts,pass=********`
`mount error(95): Operation not supported`
`Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`

Comment: i have run `smbclient //192.168.0.1/ShareRep -U requarts --signing=off` and i have got following response 'Domain=[WORKGROUP2] OS=[Darwin] Server=[@(#)PROGRAM:smbd  PROJECT:smbx-276.92.2]' `smb: \>`, and it's ok

Comment: with uid=501, `mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.0.1,unc=\\192.168.0.1\ShareRep,sec=ntlmssp,uid=501,user=requarts,pass=********`
`mount error(95): Operation not supported`
`Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`

Comment: Aha, you are using OS/X as a server. Try this: `mount --verbose -t cifs //192.168.0.1/ShareRep /home/user/share -o credentials=/usr/local/etc/whisper.credentials,uid=501,nounix,sec=ntlmssp,noperm,rw`

Comment: Thank you very much Michael, this is the solution.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the OS/X information. If you found it of use, I'd appreciate you considering accepting the answer. Thanks

Comment: Sorry Michael, i wanted to add a comment to my question, not your answer. Yes, i accept your answer and thank you again Michael.