# Mount AzureFiles on Debian using Cifs-utils

Tags: azure, debian, samba, cifs

I'm trying to mount an Azure Files storage account as a shared drive on Debian virtual machines (VMs).

```
uname -v
#1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u2 (2016-01-02)
```

I installed cifs-utils

```
sudo /sbin/mount.cifs -V
mount.cifs version: 6.4

sudo smbd -V
Version 4.1.17-Debian
```

and samba is running

```
ps aux | grep smbd
root      2442  0.0  0.3 270248 12516 ?        Ss   12:54   0:00/usr/sbin/smbd -D
root      2566  0.0  0.1 270248  6840 ?        S    12:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/smbd -D
```

Now, according to the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-how-to-use-files-linux/), one should just go with:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //whatever.file.core.windows.net/shared /mnt/shared --verbose -o -vers=3.0,username=whatever,password=MyKeyEndingIn==,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777
```

The trouble is that this yields without more information.

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=40.118.73.220,unc=\\whatever.file.core.windows.net\shared,-vers=3.0,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,user=whatever,pass=********
mount error(22): Invalid argument
```

Checking the man page did not give more information except that "user=" is an alias for "username=" parameter. Whichever I use gives the same result.

Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your error logs and remove invalid argument if exists.

   ```
   tail -f  /var/log/kern.log
   ```
2. you could refer to [Debian 7, fstab, mount.cifs Invalid argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000289/debian-7-fstab-mount-cifs-invalid-argument#answer-26000615), this maybe help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Steven for pointing me to the log where things were pretty explicit:

```
$tail -f /var/log/kern.log
[ 1331.068538] CIFS: Unknown mount option "-vers=3.0"
```

so the (ridiculous) answer is the argument should be `vers=3.0` and not `-vers=3.0`. The dash makes all the difference.